# Typescript function that accepts two objects with equal keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to declare a function with two parameters, each of which is an object. The objects should have the same keys, but the type of the values under those keys should be different (but same in each of the two objects). I tried to do this with `Record` types like this:

```js
export const combineObjects = <
    K extends Record<string | number, unknown>,
    T1,
    T2
>(
    a: Record<keyof K, T1>,
    b: Record<keyof K, T2>
): Record<keyof K, T1 & T2> => {
    ...
}
```

The problem with my solution is that if I don't specify the types manually, `T1` and `T2` get resolved to `unknown` no matter the actual type of the parameters. Can any different declaration be used so that Typescript infers the types correctly?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/we0XYW) work for you?  If not, could you provide a [mcve] of where you're getting the `unknown` types inferred?  If so, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz yes, your example works well - I should've started with a simpler approach. Do you want to submit it as an answer?

Comment: Sure thing, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that your `K` type corresponds to an object which is never directly used; no value of type `K` is passed into `combineObjects()`. The algorithm that the compiler uses to infer generic type parameters happens in a few phases, after which it gives up and falls back to types like `unknown`.  While I'm not 100% clear on the details, the gist is that the compiler first tries to infer `K` from the values passed in for the `a` and `b` arguments, which it does, but it has to defer `T1` and `T2` until after this is over, at which point it's apparently too late.

The fix here is probably to put types which are used more directly.  Since we only really care about and use the *keys* of your `K` type, we can change `K` to just be those keys:

```
declare const combineObjects: <K extends string | number, T1, T2>(
  a: Record<K, T1>,
  b: Record<K, T2>
) => Record<K, T1 & T2>;


const r = combineObjects(
  { a: { x: 123 }, b: { x: 456 } }, 
  { a: { y: "foo" }, b: { y: "bar" } }
);
r.a.x.toFixed(); // okay
r.b.y.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

Looks good. If that hadn't worked, my next step would've been to make the generic type parameters correspond *exactly* to the `a` and `b` parameters:

```
declare const combineObjects: <A extends object, B extends Record<keyof A, any>>(
  a: A,
  b: B
) => Record<keyof A, A[keyof A] & B[keyof A]>;

const r = combineObjects(
  { a: { x: 123 }, b: { x: 456 } }, 
  { a: { y: "foo" }, b: { y: "bar" } }
);
r.a.x.toFixed(); // okay
r.b.y.toUpperCase(); // okay
```

which also works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgPIBOAlgOZ76FFIAmE8GIVy8A9sCgAXJPzAAjGsAgVxAKw5CoALiQAeZiyQBpJBAAeQiMFZQkAJQ58qrNcNrAGAH2IBXCRCoAaJK+ABrYD4Ad2AAPi9NFgAVAEZIrSJogCYoojCACjSkEFVLfhs1fwgATz4AMx0fOIjs8TyrQuKyyu1q5LCogEokAF4wi0bbZoqqpDikADJxjqYtfkERKj7RPgkpGXlFKAzcHNU9-VVY5IBmJABfH3q8JCOkABYAVgA2S8ufPdzbktUAInKfD4fw+SBue1+SD+4m4IIuly6AG4olQAHQgVH6VFCPgAMRo+ggrAySKQAHoyUg+P4QCUUajxKiSti+ABVGAwTwAYRAUAgJMR5Mp1NpTGYFzmxHA0DgiCQ+P0sUYWnYnG4vAEwlW62ksgU8CUqjUugMRhMZnsUmcbg83nG8RmmWy33y1lsbXttUSYIaBXd7U6Wh6-UGfuN1SV0xSYWRkqICy1y162skuq2Bp2XwOd2OZ1B4Jzj1e7yut2+EP+gOB+ezkOhsJLSPpGKxOIVRIFQqpNLpWjRjOZOPZnKoPL5nYp3dF4slJBl5HlBOSypYqq4PFWixTGz12yNAEE9IZjKYqemhD4AEJHs2n11NUqjfc+EDAEphJ3e77PuqqS-dPoBnvYZH0qZ8kH3ABtEYwIAXSmJBL2g0CINgmMxXmTUlhWMRU02fUlF2fZbnuE5zlLAt7meN54VLLMfkrIE4WuWt-hhKg4QRZE+3RTEWXbYlSUnEVexYfsmRZYduV5fkhOFHtJQlJgLiAA)